# .Net Maui Maps Visual Region Not Updating

Tags: c#, .net, google-maps, maui

I am using .Net Maui maps.And when I navigate to map page Visible region not working, maps show all world. If I go to some other page and go back visual region is update and show good location. I try everything , on_map_loaded, OnAppearing, to delay task and nothing works. From github https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12342 I try this but that work only if I call geolocation of user, if I create new loacation this not working. Also I try to put a button below map and on click moveto region works fine.. Please help?
this is my page

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="KoloMaui.StorePage"
         Title="StorePage"
          xmlns:maps="clr-           namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps"
         xmlns:sensors="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Devices.Sensors;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Essentials">
<VerticalStackLayout>
    <Image Source="logo.png" Aspect="AspectFit" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="30" Margin="0,0,0,20"  VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Center"   />
    <maps:Map x:Name="map" HeightRequest="500" MapType="Street" Loaded="map_Loaded">
       
    </maps:Map>
    <Button x:Name="dug" Text="proba" Clicked="dug_Clicked" BackgroundColor="Red" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="150" Margin="0"></Button>
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

`

And this is code

```
public StorePage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MapSpan span = new MapSpan(new Location(44.49308778804906, 20.535900669066113), 1, 1);

    map.MoveToRegion(span);
}

private async void map_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await idi();
}

protected override void OnAppearing()
{
}

private void dug_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MapSpan span = new MapSpan(new Location(44.49308778804906, 20.535900669066113), 1, 1);

    map.MoveToRegion(span);
}

private async Task idi()
{
    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        // Introduce a small delay before invoking MoveToRegion
        await Task.Delay(1500);

        MapSpan span = new MapSpan(new Location(44.49308778804906, 20.535900669066113), 1, 1);

        map.MoveToRegion(span);
    });
}`
```

As I describe above.. I try everything I found on forums and whole net.. Onloaded method works if I am using geolocation of user .. I think because of delay or for calling maps controls. I dont know.
But if I go to some other page and get back It works, map show right region. And interesting is when I click button its also work..

```
private void dug_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MapSpan span = new MapSpan(new Location(44.49308778804906, 20.535900669066113), 1, 1);

    map.MoveToRegion(span);
}
```

Comment: You are trying to update the map in the constructor, before the UI has been loaded.  Try doing it in OnAppearing instead

Comment: I try it .. not woking .. OnAppearing method fires before Onloaded as I also try but no luck...

Comment: try: get back on MainThread before MoveToRegion. First get the task.run delay one to work that way. After delay, Dispatcher.Dispatch or MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread, wrapping the MoveToRegion. Then see if you can remove the delay. If you want, see if other places you try work with that.

Comment: I try it also.. and try with tread sleep and delay .. even for 10 sec after everything loaded.. I also try to refresh page.. no luck..

Comment: On what device did you test it? Android or iOS? What is the model and version of the device?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. When I use:

```
Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(StorePage))
```

The page does not load the map in the visible region. But if I use:

```
await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new StorePage())
```

Then the map loads just fine.

I don`t know reason. I read the documentation for .NET MAUI navigation, but did not find a reason.